# Empty excel cell using java "getNamedRange("SOME_VARIABLE")"

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007

I am project i have to modify the excel file using java codings.
My requirement is to empty the cell completely which has the string value "SOME_VARIABLE".

```
book.getNamedRange("SOME_VARIABLE").remove();
```

Is the above code a right one. I tried with this but it is not working. So I tried to write a code to check Am I deleting it in a right WORKBOOK, like if the workbook does not contain "SOME_VARIABLE" then it should inform me . That code is as follows:

```
if(book.getNamedRange("SOME_VARIABLE")== null)
            {record("the"+SOME_VARIABLE+" is not found");}
            else{
            book.getNamedRange("SOME_VARIABLE").remove();}
```

Am I going in a right path ? As i am new to handle this excelEngine I am strugling. Kindly help me friends.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided will delete the cells of the Named Range <sup>[**(ref)**](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/named-ranges.htm)</sup> `SOME_VARIABLE`.

If you want to check the `value` of the cell, you need to `find` <sup>[**(ref)**](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm)</sup> the cells that contains `SOME_VARIABLE`.